# Problem to import json file with MongoDB compass

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

**my problem is, I can't import json file in mongoDB compass**

I did export from mongodb compass, and when I want to import the same file I can't

And this is result

[image]

The probelm is in this colunm, I didn't understand why can't add it

[image]

Comment: Can you show the actual json ? At least the record which has issue

Comment: I have the same issue, have you already found a solution after 2 years? :)